# Building lists by selecting one item from each group of an IGrouping

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lets say I have a list of movies with a set of start times

```
public class Show
{
    public string Name { get; set; }      
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
}
```

Movie 1 - 8:00
Movie 1 - 10:00
Movie 1 - 12:00
Movie 2 - 9:00
Movie 2 - 11:30
Movie 2 - 15:00
Movie 3 - 12:00
Movie 3 - 13:00

I end up with a grouped list, with the name of the movie being the key. I want to take one time from each group and create a `List<DateTime>`.

Now since there are 3 items with 8 times, I should have 18 different lists.

8:00 - 9:00 - 12:00
8:00 - 9:00 - 13:00
10:00 - 9:00 - 12:00
etc.

I tried just looping through the groups

```
foreach (var movie in movies)
{
  foreach (var time in movie)
  {
     // Start looping through other groups and movies
  }
}
```

Anyways, this is either a bad solution or I wasn't doing something right because I ended up with Lists of `List<DateTime>` and I had to start looping through those lists to build more lists by only taking one item from each... It was just horrible. A regular nested `foreach` won't work because then I end up with my 8:00 Movie 1 having all instances of Movie 2 & 3, so I had to keep the lists separate and that just became too messy.

Any suggestions of a better way to approach this?

**Summary:**

An easier way to understand it would be like this, you want to see 3 movies in a single day. You know which 3 you want to see, you don't know what times you want to see them at.

I need a list that would present all the options. You can see this movie at this time, this one at this time...

e.g.

List 1 - Movie 1 - 8:00, Movie 2 - 9:00, Movie 3 - 12:00
List 2 - Movie 1 - 8:00, Movie 2 - 9:00, Movie 3 - 13:00
List 3 - Movie 1 - 8:00, Movie 2 - 11:30, Movie 3 - 12:00
etc.

Order of the list does not matter.

Comment: So what is your end goal... a list of the first time of the showing for each movie? It sounds like you're making a much more complex query when you don't need to be.

Comment: How are you deciding which time to take from each grouping? Is it the first in the list? earliest? latest?

Comment: @Adam, since I require every possible combination, it doesn't matter which gets taken. They all need to be included at some point. @Tejs, the goal is to show every possible combination of times from all movies.

Comment: It's not totally clear what is the input and what is the desired output.

Comment: @Magnus, I've updated my question. See near the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this more complex than you need to I think. If you start with a list of showtimes, then it's a simple matter of ordering to enumerate.

```
List<Show> startTimes = GetTimesFromDB();

var moviesGrouped = startTimes.GroupBy(x => x.Name);

foreach(var group in moviesGrouped)
{
    // print times for each movie
}
```

To use a concrete example, lets use this sample:

```
List<Sample> sample = new List<Sample>
        {
            new Sample { Id = 1, Time = DateTime.Now },
            new Sample { Id = 1, Time = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) },
            new Sample { Id = 2, Time = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) },
            new Sample { Id = 2, Time = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) },
            new Sample { Id = 3, Time = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4) },
        };

foreach (var group in sample.GroupBy(x => x.Id))
{
    foreach (var element in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(element.Time);
    }
}
```

You simply group by your token (in this case movie name), and then enumerate the grouping (which will contain your movie times).

However, you could greatly simplify this by changing your object model.

```
public class Movie
{
     public int MovieId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public List<Showing> Showings { get; set; }
}

public class Showing
{
     public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
     public List<Seat> UnsoldSeats { get; set; }
     // Etc
}
```

Then when you have a `List<Movie>`, it's already set up to do that display, and it naturally makes more sense than a simple showing class.

```
foreach(var movie in movies)
{
    foreach(var showing in movie.Showings)
       // DoStuff
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I can't change the domain model. Your solution doesn't really explain how I would be able to combine all the showings of one movie with those of another. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: thanks, however I've already gotten to that point. I have a grouping already, and I tried enumerating it. In the second code sample of my question along with the explanation that follows, the part where I get stuck is how to build a list of every possible combination of datetimes. You're right, changing the domain model to the way you suggested would make enumerating easier, but that is not what I am having problems with. My problem is with buildling a list of DateTimes. My explanations are probably very poor, I added a summary to the bottom of my question if it helps.

Comment: In that case, all you need to do is attach a where to your grouping. `.Where(x => someOtherListOfMovies.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name)).GroupBy(x => x.Name)`